# node.js package.json, passing arguments to bin scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

So I've published two npm packages so far, but for the next project I want to do it would be necessary for a user to be able to pass in command line commands to the executable scripts in the bin section of my package.json

"

```
bin": {
  "doSomething": "passAnArgumentToMeFromTheCommandLine.js",
}
```

So, assuming end users, and myself, will be globally installing this package, how can i allow them to pass arguments to "passAnArgumentToMeFromTheCommandLine.js" through the command line?

Answer (score -1):

Node supports parameters by default, you don't need to do anything special in the `package.json`, it's up to you to ensure your app parses & handles the expected args - see [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)